problemas ao usar pytorch no vs code
estou tendo problemas ao tentar usar o torch
já tentei instalar o torch varias vezes, utilizando:
pip install torch
e
pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu121
até mesmo adicionei o local onde foi instalado ao path no Windows, porém isso não resolveu meu problema, continuo sempre recebendo o mesmo problema:
[{
"resource": "/C:/Users/Noah/Desktop/project chatbot/chat2.py",
"owner": "generated_diagnostic_collection_name#2",
"code": {
"value": "reportMissingImports",
"target": {
"$mid": 1,
"external": "https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/blob/main/docs/configuration.md#reportMissingImports",
"path": "/microsoft/pyright/blob/main/docs/configuration.md",
"scheme": "https",
"authority": "github.com",
"fragment": "reportMissingImports"
}
},
"severity": 4,
"message": "Import "torch" could not be resolved",
"source": "Pylance",
"startLineNumber": 1,
"startColumn": 8,
"endLineNumber": 1,
"endColumn": 13
}]
e esse ao tentar executar:
PS C:\Users\Noah> & "C:/Program Files (x86)/Python38-32/python.exe" "c:/Users/Noah/Desktop/project chatbot/chat2.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:/Users/Noah/Desktop/project chatbot/chat2.py", line 1, in 
import torch
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'

Esta pergunta já foi postada e lá já foram fornecidas as orientações relevantes. Desta forma, o espaço de comentários foi desativado aqui para evitar descentralização de informações (mas continua disponível na postagem original).
